# httpput authentication is not working

Tags: java, android, http-status-code-401, http-put

I am using below code to authenticate on server.

```
DefaultHttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
          new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(Url);
HttpResponse response = Client.execute(put);
```

If I use get it will work fine for me.

but when I use **HttpPut** it's not working .

```
DefaultHttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
          new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

   HttpPut put = new HttpPut(Url);
   HttpResponse response = Client.execute(put);
```

I need to upload file on server, so need to use HttpPut for this.

This will through 401 (authentication) error.

Can anybody have idew, why did I face this issue?

Thanks,
Embedded Team

Comment: why -1 ? is there for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate through `httpGET` and than upload file using `httpPUT`, make sure you save `cookies`.

Why `httpPut` doesn't work? maybe its server side requirement to authenticate using `GET`. But surely it's a bad idea to use `GET` request for `auth`.